# How do I clear my TextBox using MVVM after my Command fires

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, textbox

I have my MainWindow with a TextBox control on it.

```
<Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="messageBox" Margin="252,89,277,300">
            <TextBox.InputBindings>
                <KeyBinding Key="Enter"
                            Command="{Binding TextCommand}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding Text, ElementName=messageBox}"/>
            </TextBox.InputBindings>
        </TextBox>
    </Grid>
```

And as you can see I have bound the `Enter` key to when I click Enter it promts a MessageBox with the text I provided in the TextBox.
My question is.. How do i clear the textbox after I press enter? I don't want to call an Event on the Control because that will defeat the purpose of MVVM, it will also clutter up my MainWindow.cs

As you can see I've set the DataContext in my MainWindow like so..

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ServerViewModel();
    }
}
```

And here is my ServerViewModel.cs

```
class ServerViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public TextBoxCommand TextCommand { get; }
        public ServerViewModel()
        {
            TextCommand = new TextBoxCommand(SendMessage);
        }

        private void SendMessage(string parameter)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(parameter);
            parameter = "";
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

And the command if that's worth looking at.

```
class TextBoxCommand : ICommand
    {
        public Action<string> _sendMethod;

        public TextBoxCommand(Action<string> SendMethod)
        {
            _sendMethod = SendMethod;
        }
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _sendMethod.Invoke((string)parameter);
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    }
```

Comment: "MessageBox.Show(parameter);" in MVVM, it is not good to have references to view inside the VM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can bind your TextBox to a property on your ViewModel and reset the TextBox just by setting the property to empty.

The binding:

```
<TextBox x:Name="messageBox" Text="{Binding TextBoxInput, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

The new property in the ViewModel:

```
    public string TextBoxInput
    {
        get { return _textBoxInput; }
        set
        {
            _textBoxInput = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TextBoxInput));
        }
    }
    private string _textBoxInput;
```

The TextBox is reset here:

```
    private void SendMessage(string parameter)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(parameter);
        TextBoxInput = "";
    }
```

Comment: "You can bind your TextBox to a property on your ViewMode" it is weird because MVVM is all about binding.